# Magento - skip one of order steps

Tags: php, magento

Is a there a way to skip a "Order Review" step from Checkout process? I need to remove last step from order to make it faster.

Comment: http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2014/04/remove-shipping-method-and-order-review.html may be it will help you